# C++ implicit constructor conversion followed by type upcast

Tags: c++

I have a program that has a base class `Value` with multiple subclasses (e.g. `IntValue`) that inherit from `Value`. Each of these classes have constructors that accept one or more parameters. Here is example code showing what I'd like to be able to do:

```
#include <iostream>

class Value {
public:
  Value() {}
  virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const {}
};

class IntValue: public Value {
public:
  IntValue(int val): val_(val) {}
  void print(std::ostream& os) const override { os << val_; }
private:
  int val_;
};

class VariableValue: public Value {
public:
  VariableValue(const std::string& name): name_(name) {}
  void print(std::ostream& os) const override { os << name_; }
private:
  const std::string name_;
};

void emit_add(const Value& lhs, const Value& rhs, std::ostream& os) {
  lhs.print(os);
  os << " + ";
  rhs.print(os);
  os << std::endl;
}

template <class ValueType>
void emit_add(const ValueType& lhs, const ValueType& rhs, std::ostream &os) {
  lhs.print(os);
  os << " + ";
  rhs.print(os);
  os << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  // all these work                                                                              
  emit_add<IntValue>(12, 13, std::cout); // implicit constructors                                
  emit_add<VariableValue>(std::string("x"), std::string("y"), std::cout); // implicit constructo\
rs                                                                                               
  emit_add(VariableValue(std::string("x")), IntValue(1), std::cout); // implicit upcasting       

  // this doesn't                                                                                
  emit_add(std::string("x"), 13, std::cout); // implicit constor + implicit upcasting            

  return -1;
}
```

When I try to compile using `clang 9.1.0`, I get the following error:

```
test.cpp:47:3: error: no matching function for call to 'emit_add'
  emit_add(std::string("x"), 13, std::cout); // implicit constor + implicit upcasting
  ^~~~~~~~
test.cpp:25:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::string' (aka
      'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') to 'const Value' for 1st
      argument
void emit_add(const Value& lhs, const Value& rhs, std::ostream& os) {
     ^
test.cpp:33:6: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter
      'ValueType' ('std::__1::basic_string<char>' vs. 'int')
void emit_add(const ValueType& lhs, const ValueType& rhs, std::ostream &os) {
     ^
1 error generated.
```

My understanding is that the compiler is failing to call the implicit constructor for `VariableValue` AND THEN upcast it to type `Value`, but it can clearly do both *individually*.

Is it possible to force the compiler to do this?

Comment: `void emit_add(const Value& lhs,...` and you call with `std::string` as the first argument. You can force the compiler if you overload the std::string operator()

Comment: This is a bad usage of inheritance.  Your task is more easily accomplished in C++ by using [templates](https://www.ideone.com/CZXRIL), not inheritance.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: No templates needed here, just plain old function overloading.

Comment: Side note: don't add `std::endl` in your printing output (you did so for `VariableValue` - you can't get rid of if you want to print e. g. `name = "some name"` (adding quotes around)...

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This code is taken out of context from the project I'm working on, in which it makes perfect sense to use inheritance.

Comment: @NicholasMosier -- I'm going by what you posted.  To be honest, this looks like a Java programmer's attempt to make C++ look like Java in terms of Integer, String, etc. being derived from a "god" object, and that almost never turns out well.

Answer (score 2):

A `VariableValue` is a `Value` (because inheritance is an "is a" relationship), but `Value` is not an `VariableValue` (the "is a" relationship of inheritance is one-way).

What I'm trying to say is that if you have a `VariableValue` object, you can easily go up the inheritance chain to get a `Value` object (or reference of it). But you can't go the other way, down the inheritance chain from a `Value` object, without being explicit about it.

You need to explicitly construct a `VariableValue` object and pass it to your function:

```
emit_add(VariableValue(x), 13, std::cout);
```

Comment: He's not trying to go the wrong way, the mistake is in expecting the compiler to infer a type that doesn't appear in any of the types or function signature.

Comment: See the edits I made. `emit_add(VariableValue(x), IntValue(13), std::cout);` works, but I'm lazy and I don't want to go through 1500+ lines of code and wrap the parameters of each call to `emit_add`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following as *counter*-example:

```
class Value
{
public:
    Value() { }
    Value(int) { }
    Value(std::string const&) { }
};

emit_add(x, 13, std::cout);
```

This now *would* have worked as the compiler sees `emit_add` accepting two `Value`s and `Value` having appropriate non-explicit constructors accepting `std::string` and `int`.

What C++ does *not* provide is inferring *derived* classes from base class according to given arguments, as [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) [denoted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52014289/1312382) already.

You could, though, provide a wrapper to do this work for you:

```
class Wrapper
{
    std::unique_ptr<Value> value;
public:
    Wrapper(int n) : value(new IntValue(n)) { }
    Wrapper(std::string) : value(new VariableValue(n)) { }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Wrapper const& w)
    {
        w.value->print(s);
        return s;
    }
};
```

If that's really better than specifying the types directly (as Some programmer dude did) is a matter of taste. On the other hand, as defined above (with `operator<<`), you now can do:

```
void emit_add(Wrapper const& lhs, Wrapper const& rhs, std::ostream& os)
{
    os << lhs << " + " << rhs << std::endl;
}
```

which is a little more comfortable as well...

Another approach could be an overloaded template:

```
void emit_add(Value const& x, Value const& y, std::ostream& os);

template <typename TX, typename TY>
void emit_add(TX&& x, TY&& y, std::ostream& os)
{
    emit_add
    (
            static_cast<Value const&>(TheValue<TX>(std::forward<TX>(x))),
            static_cast<Value const&>(TheValue<TY>(std::forward<TY>(y))),
            os
    );
}
```

The casts above are necessary as otherwise, the template itself would be a better match and the non-template would not be selected, resulting in endless recursion. I converted the concrete values into a template for:

```
template <typename T>
class TheValue : public Value
{
public:
    TheValue(T&& t)
            : val_(std::forward<T>(t))
    {  }
    void print(std::ostream& os) const override
    {
        os << val_;
    }
private:
    T val_;
};
```

If this default pattern does not match your concrete needs for a specific type, you can specialise it for that type to suite your needs.

If you still need the original type names, you can alias them:

```
using IntValue = TheValue<int>;
```

Finally, if it is *solely* for printing out, you can do it directly, circumventing the `Value` class entirely:

```
template <typename TX, typename TY>
void emit_add(TX&& x, TY&& y, std::ostream& os)
{
    std::cout << std::forward<TX>(x) << " + " << std::forward<TY>(y) << std::endl;
}
```

If you now have some custom types you want to print, just provide an `operator<<` overload for, such as for the following point example:

```
template <typename T>
class Point
{
    T m_x, m_y;
public:
    // constructors, calculations, ... (whatever you might need/find useful)
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, Point const& p)
    {
        s << '(' p.m_x << ", " << p.m_y << ')';
    }
};
```

Side note: The friend operator as above is convenient for your own data types (it still defines a *free standing* function), just if you did:

```
template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, Point<T> const& p)
{
    s << '(' p.x() << ", " << p.y() << ')';
}
```

outside the class (you still can declare it friend inside; if you don't or can't, you cannot use private members, of course, so you rely on the public interface as demonstrated above, assuming `x` and `y` are the public getters).

Comment: Doesn't need to be a class at all, in the context of the original question.  A few function overloads will do it.

Comment: @PaulSanders If function is complex, you possibly don't want to repeat the code all the time. Converting to an intermediate representation (e. g. std::string) could solve, but might fail in the future if this intermediate representation does not fit the needs of a new stream (e. g. one storing binary data to a file). Additionally, you might need quite a lot of overloads (int + int, string + int, int + string, string + string and then again paired with double, unsigned long, custom classes, ...).

Comment: @Aconcagua Exactly. In the actual code, I have 4 different kinds of `Value`s. This would mean 4^2 = 16 different function overloads, each of whose implementations would be exactly the same. There must be a better way.

Comment: @NicholasMosier You could *generate* these overloads, though, by use of a template. Added some lines to my answer for.

Comment: I think what we really need here is a clearer statement of what the problem is. Questions that start by proposing a solution rarely lead to productive discussion.

Comment: @PaulSanders Or to answers growing larger and larger such as this one... Looks pretty much as if we have an xy-problem here. Strange - how did it come that I did not recognise one of my favourites here???

Comment: I will take bets that the issue is one of trying to make C++ look like some other language's object hierarchy, i.e. where "simple types" (i.e. integer, string, etc.) are derived from some base `Object` in some way (Java maybe?).  The original question has all the earmarks of such an attempt.